# SQL Aggregation across two tables with complex (> and <) join criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to do some complex aggregation on two table (representing data in wells).

```
Table 1
ID FM TODEPTH FROMDEPTH
1  A    1       20
1  B    20      60
1  C    60      100
2  A    1       30
2  B    30      40
2  C    40      80
...

Table 2
ID VAL1 VAL2   TODEPTH FROMDEPTH
1   0.2  0.4    18       19
1   0.3  0.5    19       20
1   0.1  0.2    55       58
1   0.2  0.3    58       59
1   0.5  0.8    62       68
1   0.6  1.2    72       75
...

and desired output is:
ID  FM  Avg(Val1)  Avg(val2)
1   A    0.3       0.4
1   B    0.1       0.2
1   C    0.6       0.9
2   A    0.2       0.4
....
```

The aggregation rule is `select values from Table2 where ID = table1.ID and todepth >= table1.todepth and fromdepth <= table1.fromdepth, average on table1.FM`

I am struggling to see whether this can be written in SQL or do I need to go to code.

Comment: Seems like it would be pretty easily written in SQL... What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.fm, AVG(t2.val1), AVG(t2.val2)
FROM 
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t2.todepth >= t1.todepth
    AND t2.fromdepth <= t1.fromdepth
GROUP BY 
    t1.id, t1.fm
```

Comment: Works for me. My complication was that "table1" was not actually a table but another select query. However, with template for guidance I think I have it figured

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  T1.ID,
  T1.FM,
  COALESCE(AVG(T2.VAL1), 0) as AVGVAL1,
  COALESCE(AVG(T2.VAL2), 0) as AVGVAL2
FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.ID
      AND T1.TODEPTH <= T2.TODEPTH
      AND T1.FROMDEPTH >= T2.FROMDEPTH
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.FM
```

Answer (score 0):

The rounding in your expected result set looks a little funny, but here's a query and you can modify with cast, round, ceiling and/or floor functions as necessary.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.FM, CAST(AVG(Table2.Val1) AS DECIMAL(2,1)), CAST(AVG(Table2.Val2) AS DECIMAL(2,1))
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 
   ON Table1.iD = Table2.ID 
   AND Table2.TODEPTH >= Table1.TODEPTH 
   AND Table2.FROMDEPTH <= Table1.FROMDEPTH
GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.FM
```